# Facebook API failing with strange error: Object Story Spec

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been looking this error message everywhere and I cannot find it:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 2446211,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "First Dof Value Should Match Object Story Spec Field",
    "error_user_msg": "For a Degrees of freedom enabled ad, the first value of Asset Feed Spec field should match the corresponding field in Object Story Spec.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AKOUMOZmQksWf9lDtUw0XSc
"
  }
}
```

Request:

```
act_XXXX/adcreatives?access_token=XXXXX&fields=account_id%2Cactor_id%2Cadlabels%2Capplink_treatment%2Casset_feed_spec%2Cauto_update%2Cbody%2Cbranded_content_sponsor_page_id%2Ccall_to_action_type%2Ccategorization_criteria%2Cdestination_set_id%2Ceffective_authorization_category%2Ceffective_instagram_story_id%2Ceffective_object_story_id%2Cid%2Cimage_crops%2Cimage_hash%2Cimage_url%2Cinstagram_permalink_url%2Cinstagram_story_id%2Cinteractive_components_spec%2Clink_deep_link_url%2Clink_og_id%2Clink_url%2Cmessenger_sponsored_message%2Cname%2Cobject_id%2Cobject_store_url%2Cobject_story_id%2Cobject_story_spec%2Cobject_type%2Cobject_url%2Cplace_page_set_id%2Cplatform_customizations%2Cplayable_asset_id%2Cportrait_customizations%2Cproduct_set_id%2Crecommender_settings%2Cstatus%2Ctemplate_url%2Ctemplate_url_spec%2Cthumbnail_url%2Ctitle%2Curl_tags%2Cuse_page_actor_override%2Cimage_file&summary=true&limit=25&after=MjM4NDM4MTAzMzgwMTAzMTMZD
```

It fails after the page 450 so it is for sure an ad creative that has some wrong data. Is there a way to filter it? I am blocked on this.

Ps. I am able to reproduce it on the graph explorer too.

Thank you.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I ran into the same issue

Comment: yes it was that the user for the api did not have permissions for the page that was used in the ad.